# Missing ACKs on I²C

Tags: esp8266, i2c

I am using a GY-521 accelerometer as well as BMP280 pressure sensors via I²C on an ESP8266.

When I analyze I²C data with the oscilloscope, I can see missing ACKs on both of them as shown in the pictures.

Is that something to worry about or is it just normal, considering I bought cheap Chinese sensors?

[image: Missing ACK on GY-521]

[image: Missing ACK on BMP280]

My BMP280 code is this:

```
// https://github.com/mahfuz195/BMP280-arduino-library
#include <BMP280.h>
BMP280 bmp280;

#include "Wire.h"
TwoWire i2c = TwoWire();

// Hardware setup
#define CLOCK_PIN D1
#define DATA_PIN D2
#define I2C_SPEED 400000

// I²C response codes
#define FOUND 0
#define NORESPONSE 2

bool sensorAvailableAt(byte address)
{
   i2c.beginTransmission(address);
   byte response = i2c.endTransmission();
   return response == FOUND;
}

void stop(char* message){
  Serial.println(message);
  while(true);
}

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200); 
  while(!Serial){} // Waiting for serial connection

  i2c.begin(DATA_PIN, CLOCK_PIN, I2C_SPEED);
  if (!sensorAvailableAt(0x76))
  {
    stop("BMP280 sensor not found");
  }

  if (bmp280.begin())
  {
    Serial.println("BMP280 init success");
  }
  else
  {
    stop("BMP280 initialization failed.");
  }
}

void loop() {
  double temperature;
  double pressure;
  bmp280.getTemperatureAndPressure(temperature, pressure);
  double sealevel = bmp280.sealevel(pressure, 800);
  
  Serial.print("Temperature: ");
  Serial.print(temperature,1);
  Serial.println(" °C");

  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(pressure, 1);
  Serial.println(" mbar (absolute)");

  Serial.print("Pressure: ");
  Serial.print(sealevel);
  Serial.println(" mbar (sealevel, compensated for 800 m height)");

  delay(50);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure, how the images are to be interpeted. A NACK at the end of the transmission (before the stop condition) is normal and belongs to the I2C protocol. The master signals that way, that it does not want to read more data.

Comment: @chrisl: ah, that's valuable. I'll try to find more on that

Comment: Can you confirm, that the "missing ACK"/NACK happens on the end of every master read action? If yes, I will formulate that as an answer.

Comment: @chrisl: yes, that's what I see and how I interpret the data. Do I get it right that this should only happen with a dedicated sensor library, where the implementation knows how much data to expect? In case of a more generic I²C implementation, the master would not know how much data there is to read and thus would not stop the transmission?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NACK at the end of a master read/slave send transmission is normal expected behavior.

In I2C communication the acknowledgement is a possibility to react to send data. For example, when the slave sends a NACK while the master sends data to it, it might be, because it currently cannot process further data. Acknowledgement goes in both ways, depending on the direction of transmission. The reader always needs to acknowledge the data to mark a successful transmission. It is normal for the master to send a NACK on the end of it's reading cycle to mark, that it doesn't want to receive more data. While this isn't strictly logically needed (since the end of a transmission is marked by the master by a STOP or RESTART condition), it is done nonetheless.

I think I have also seen this behavior with the `Wire` library of Arduino. So it comes down to the implementation of the I2C protocol in your case. As your library simply uses the `Wire` library, the behavior is not part of it. The I2C protocol is implemented by `Wire`. You would see the same behavior in every sensor library, that uses the `Wire` library.

You can read more about the I2C protocol at [this site](https://i2c.info/i2c-bus-specification).